# Encryption of csv before Upload

Tags: security, encryption, blob, azure-blob-storage, adfs2.0

We have a windows service which monitors a folder (using filewatcher of C#) for files and uploads the files to a blob. Windows service retrieves the Write only SAS token , which is used to generate the blob client to upload to a blob, from a WebAPI endpoint(TLS 1.2) secured with ADFS 2.0 by passing the JWT retrieved from ADFS WS-Trust 1.3 endpoint passing user name and password.

My experience is limited in the area of security. I have two questions.

1- Should there be an encryption before I upload the data to blob? If yes, how can I implement it.

2- Would retrieving the SAS token from an endpoint, even though it is secured with ADFS and is over https, possess any kind of security risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- Should there be an encryption before I upload the data to blob? If yes, how can I implement it.

Per my understanding, if you want extra security during transit and your stored data to be encrypted, you could leverage **Client-side encryption** and refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault). At this point, you need to make programmatic changes to your application.

Also, you could leverage **Storage Service Encryption (SSE)** which does not provide for the security of the data in transit, but it provides the following benefit:

> SSE allows the storage service **automatically encrypt the data when writing it to Azure Storage**. When you read the data from Azure Storage, **it will be decrypted by the storage service before being returned**. This enables you to secure your data without having to modify code or add code to any applications.

I would recommend you could just leverage HTTPs for your data in transit and SSE to encrypt your blobs. For how to enable SSE, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption). Additionally, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide) about Azure Storage security guide.

> 2- Would retrieving the SAS token from an endpoint, even though it is secured with ADFS and is over https, possess any kind of security risk

SAS provides you with a way to grant the limited permissions to resources in your storage account to other clients. For security consideration, you could set interval over which your SAS is valid. Also, you could limit the IP addresses which could Azure Storage would accept the SAS. Per my understanding, the endpoint for generating SAS token is secured with ADFS 2.0 over HTTPs, I assumed that it is safe enough.